# The construction “avoir beau” + infinitif

Tags: expressions, sens, infinitif, constructions

I recently came across a sentence of a poem from Victor Hugo,

> On a beau tout rêver, tu dépasses le rêve.

([see here](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/L%E2%80%99Amour_%28Hugo%29#IV._En_Gr.C3.A8ce_.21), twelveth-to-last line in the penultimate paragraph).

I'd like to understand how this *avoir + infinitif* construction works grammatically.
Are there any restrictions on the kind of adjectives one can use? A French-speaker I asked said he would only use it with "beau".

He translated (e.g.) "On a beau dire,..." as "Even if we say,...". Is this the only interpretation? How would this construction be interpreted, resp. translated (as well as possible) in general?

Also, I'd like to make sure I understand the meaning of the above quote as well as possible, as my French is a bit rusty after a long time without use)...

From what I've understood so far (in the context of a poem about love), I'd translate it (very loosely) as:

> No matter what I dream(ed) about, you surpass my dream(s).

I don't expect this to be a very good try, so I'd welcome any feedback.

Comment: Welcome to FL Axel. Very interesting question about *avoir beau*. Old timers are here to help new timers find their bearings on the site, so don't take the following remark personally. Maybe you could rephrase your "I'd like a translation", which in fact you aren't when we read to the end, you just want to know if you have understood properly. [We do not translate as such](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but anyway we would never translate into English, we could advise on a proposed translation into French.

Comment: @Laure: Thanks for the tip, I edited my answer accordingly (and hope it ok now).

Comment: No need to apologize... (By the way, we don't use thanks either on stackexchange.). I've modified your edit , to avoid making it too heavy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Avoir beau + un infinitif* est une locution verbale.

En français l’infinitif peut jouer le rôle d'un nom, on parle d'« adjectif substantivé », et c'est le cas dans l’expression *avoir beau* suivie d'un infinitif.

*Avoir beau* + inf. peut exprimer :

- une oppostion :

  > Il a beau être riche, il n'est pas heureux.
- une opposition à laquelle s'ajoute une idée de répétition et d'inutilité :

  > Il a beau courir 20 kilomètres tous les jours, il ne maigrit pas.
  >   Tu auras beau pleurer, tu n'auras pas de bonbon.

**[Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/beau)**  dit qu'*avoir beau faire* vient de *avoir beau* :

> « La locution avoir beau pour dire faire inutilement, peut s'expliquer ainsi : avoir beau, c'est toujours avoir beau champ, beau temps, belle occasion ; avoir beau faire, c'est proprement avoir tout favorable pour faire. Voilà le sens ancien et naturel. Mais par une ironie facile à comprendre, avoir beau a pris le sens d'avoir le champ libre, de pouvoir faire ce qu'on voudra, et, par suite, de se perdre en vains efforts. Vous avez beau dire, c'est, primitivement, il est bien à vous de dire ; puis, vous pouvez dire, on vous permet de dire, mais cela ne servira à rien. »

La seule autre locution verbale à laquelle je pense et qui utilise la même construction adj+infinitif, c'est la tournure impersonnelle *il fait bon* (parfois adapté en *il fait doux*).

> Il fait bon rêver allongé dans l'herbe fraîche.
>   Il fait doux s'asseoir au coin du feu.

---

*Avoir beau* followed by an infinitive is a verb phrase where the infinitive has the role of a noun.

It can express :

- an opposition

  > Il a beau être riche, il n'est pas heureux<sup>1</sup>.
- an opposition, implying repetition and uselessness  :

  > Tu auras beau pleurer, tu n'auras pas de bonbon<sup>2</sup>.

The only other verb phrase I know where an adjective is followed by an infinitive is the impersonal turn of phrase *il fait bon* (sometimes expressed as *il fait doux*)

> Il fait bon  être assis au coin du feu.<sup>3</sup>.

<sup>1. Rich as he is, he isn't happy.</sup>
<sup>2. Cry as you might, you won't get a sweet.</sup>
<sup>3. It's nice to sit by the fireside.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

*No matter what I dream(ed) about* donnerait *quoi que j'ai rêvé ...*

*[Reverso](http://www.reverso.net/translationresults.aspx?lang=FR&direction=francais-anglais)* traduit la phrase de Victor Hugo par *We may dream about everything ...*, je dirais plutôt *we may have dreamed about everything*.

L'idée est que l'on a épuisé tous les rêves (éveillés ou endormis) créés par notre imagination sans pouvoir créer le rêve que l'amour réalise.

Il faut donc traduire la notion *d'épuisement des possibilités des rêves* pour arriver à son dépassement, ce ne sont pas des rêves quelconques, mais tous les rêves que l'on peut faire avant de connaître l'amour.