# « Avoir beau » sans infinitif ni proposition qui ne suit ?

Tags: expressions, oral, québec, régionalismes

> — Veux-tu que je mette tes clés en avant ?
>  — *T'as beau*... [dans le sens de : *tu peux* (*bien*)...]

La question porte sur l'origine et le sens de l'emploi particulier qu'on fait, semble-t-il, d'« *avoir [beau](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/beau)* » ([2](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/beau/8515/locution?q=avoir%20beau#168695)) au Québec :

> En français québécois, avoir beau, avoir bien beau de, à (et
>   infinitif) « avoir la possibilité, pouvoir ».
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sous dir. A. Rey,
>   ed. *Le Robert*, à *beau* ]

D'un sens usuel et compris de tous : « *J'ai eu beau donner de la voix, personne, hélas, n'est venu me détacher* (Camus, *La Dévotion à la croix*, adapté de Calderon de La Barca, 1953, p. 574). » (*TLFi*). Il s'agit de la chose espérée, suivie de la déception (*TLFi* : III, B., avoir beau + inf.; avoir beau dire, avoir beau faire etc.), de la chose qui se révèle inutile dans les circonstances. La parenté étymologique de *beau*, *bon* et *bien* jette un éclairage sur les sens générés avec *beau* (*DHLF/Rey*). J'aimerais savoir pourquoi on dit qu'on a ce sens de *possible* au Québec et pas ailleurs. J'ai pensé à une similarité avec [*l'avoir belle de*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/beau_belle/8514/locution) : « *Vieux. L'avoir belle de, être dans une situation favorable pour faire quelque chose*. » (*Larousse*). Il ne semble pas y avoir cette idée d'opposition dans ce cas, et on revient au *sens ancien et naturel* dont on parle au *Littré* (voir cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11333)). Voici un exemple avec cette idée similaire d'*avoir des chances de réussite* :

> *S'ils avaient organisé la résistance à Paris, comme je le conseillais, et forcé la main du Roi, ils l'avaient belle de boucler
>   la sédition en cinq secs et de remettre tout en place.*
>
> [ L. Daudet, *Les Lys sanglants*, 1938, p. 167., ex. au *TLFi* @[belle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/belle) ]

Y a-t-il un lien entre *l'avoir belle*/*avoir beau* généralement et *avoir beau* au Québec ? L'idée d'*inutilité* est-elle comprise dans la locution en soi ou dans la proposition qui la suit (quel est l'impact de ne pas avoir la proposition suivant la locution) ? Depuis quand a-t-on cet usage au Québec ? Est-ce vraiment exclusif au Québec / ne l'entend-on pas du tout ailleurs dans la langue parlée conjugué à la deuxième personne (sing., plur.) ?

Comment: Concernant la toute dernière question, je ne connaissais absolument pas cette définition d'_avoir beau_. Je ne l'ai jamais entendue que ce soit en France métropolitaine (mais je suis loin de maîtriser toutes les particularités régionales) ou en discutant de nos différences de langue avec mes collègues belges. _Avoir beau_ sans infinitif derrière est une construction que je ne connaissais pas.

Comment: @Chop Merci pour l'info. Si on entendait « t'as beau y aller », on comprendrait « tu perds ton temps » ?

Comment: Cette construction semble bancale. On attend vraiment une contrepartie. « J'ai eu beau _faire quelque chose_, _la contrepartie espérée ne s'est pas produite_. » [Le Wiktionnaire le définit](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_beau) avec « Bien que : malgré que » (ce dernier me paraît toujours faux) et la construction est similaire : on a l'essai et l'échec.

Comment: @Chop Merci ! Bien intéressant ce tout ou rien. C'est en partie une réponse à la deuxième question en plus de la dernière. On peut sans doute réunir ça dans une réponse partielle. Ne pas hésiter !

Comment: Je vis au Québec et j'ai jamais entendu cette expression la, du moins dans les grandes villes.

Comment: Je vis au Québec et j'ai déjà entendu cette expression-là, dans une grande ville, venant de quelqu'un qui ne venait pas d'une grande ville. J'ai dû me la faire expliquer, et ça collait parfaitement aux définitions citées.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je confirme l'usage et le sens d'*avoir beau* au Québec. (« *T'as ben beau.* » = tu peux bien le faire, peu importe.)

Le lien entre *l'avoir belle de* et *avoir beau* me semble établi (ça serait trop beau pour être une coïncidence). [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/beau) a tout dit : *l'avoir belle*/*beau*, c'est être dans une situation favorable, et par ironie, que tout effort soit inutile.

> [«](http://www.littre.org/definition/beau) La locution avoir beau pour dire faire inutilement, peut s'expliquer ainsi : avoir beau, c'est toujours avoir beau champ, beau temps, belle occasion ; avoir beau faire, c'est proprement avoir tout favorable pour faire. Voilà le sens ancien et naturel. Mais par une ironie facile à comprendre, avoir beau a pris le sens d'avoir le champ libre, de pouvoir faire ce qu'on voudra, et, par suite, de se perdre en vains efforts. [...] [»](http://www.littre.org/definition/beau)

L'inutilité me semble située dans la locution elle-même, c'est-à-dire dans l'usage qui en est fait. L'ironie de la tournure est entrée dans la langue et est devenue le sens premier de l'expression. Ça ne serait pas la première locution à se faire rattraper par son usage, « *C'est malin !* » serait un exemple semblable.

Par contre, de quoi la locution clame-t-elle l'inutilité... de la proposition qui la suit ! Même si cette dernière parait absente, « *t'as beau* » est toujours une *réponse*, qui fait référence à ce que vient de dire l'autre interlocuteur.

> — Veux-tu que je mette tes clés en avant ?
>   — T'as beau [mettre mes clefs en avant] (— c'est un vain effort).

Comment: L'emploie-t-on ailleurs qu'au Québec / depuis quand ceci signifie-t-il cela là : je ne sais.

Comment: Merci ! J'étais bien curieux de savoir s'il y avait un usage commun entre le Québec et la France mais c'est toujours difficile à étayer de la part d'une seule personne.

Answer (score 1):

Illustration du sens bien connu « malgré » : « on a beau emprunter la route du nord, le trajet nous paraît toujours aussi long » -
Sens de sa très vielle utilisation au Québec qui se rapproche…..effectivement de « l’avoir belle » : debout devant son champ de fraises, un fermier raconte à son voisin combien il aime les fraises….et son voisin de lui répondre : « t’as beau ! » J’ai l’âge qu’il faut pour l’utiliser aussi souvent que possible et faire rire mes compatriotes ! On a beau!